# How do I retrieve the name of the lowest subclass from the context of the superclass in Java?

Tags: java, debugging, stack-trace

#### Rational

I would like to have more detailed logging debugging/logging output on a few superclasses, so the subclass name will not actually be effecting real-time performance nor application logic. I'm also of the opinion that it is fairly bad design to do this normally, however I really do want this info to be logged during development runs.

#### Question

Suppose I have a simple class structure as below, how do I pull the name of the subclass into the superclass without having to explicitly pass a reference?

```
public abstract AbstractClass {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public AbstractClass() {}

    public void execute(ContextObject context) {
        if (logger.debuggingEnabled()) {
            String invokingClassName = ""; // <-- how do I get this?
            logger.debug("Executing {}", invokingClassName);
        }
        // shared application logic is here...
    }
}

public MyClass extends AbstractClass {
    public MyClass() {}

    @Override
    public void execute(ContextObject context) {
        super.execute(context);
        // application logic...
    }
}
```

I have worked with parsing stack traces before and I suspect that is the route I will have to go if I want this information. Does anyone know of a library that will do this for me or a good code snippet?

Comment: imho a better approach is to create a DebuggingDecorator, a decorator that wraps an "execute" with the needed info

Comment: class keyword is expected both in MyClass and in AbstractClass

Comment: if the answers cleared things for you, they will do so for the next person with the same problem :) keep the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't [`this.getClass().getName()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) do the trick? Namely:

```
public void execute(ContextObject context) {
    if (logger.debuggingEnabled()) {
        String invokingClassName = ""; // <-- how do I get this?
        logger.debug("Executing {}", this.getClass().getName());
    }
    // shared application logic is here...
}
```

Comment: Wow. Do I feel stupid. Why was I under the impression that getClass() would return the abstract class instance... Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You've already got that information when you execute this line:

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

That means you'll be logging with a category for the *actual* class. As that information is in the log already, I don't think it makes much sense to *also* include it in the `execute` method. Just make sure that your log output format includes the category name and it should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to log the class name explicitly. Log4j already do that. The way you have defined your Logger will do the trick. Check your log file.